# Restructure XML based on substring using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I got a question which I'm not sure it can be done. i'm searching through the Stackpages and I still don't have a clue.

In have the following Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<files count="5" filemask="*.*">
    <folder>D:\PlanetPress\PPWorkdir\debug\output\20210107\DAGSET20210107\
        <file>
            <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_1_02001_2001_Brief.pdf</filename>
        </file>
        <file>
            <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_2_02001_2001_NotaXML.pdf</filename>
        </file>
        <file>
            <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_5_02001_02001_Prov.pdf</filename>
        </file>
        <file>
            <filename>ZZ001_AA117_00030393_1_80001__Brief.pdf</filename>
        </file>
        <file>
            <filename>ZZ001_AA117_00030393_2_80001__NotaXML.pdf</filename>
        </file>
    </folder>
</files>
```

I would like to change it to something like

```
<files>
    <ID>AB001_AA107_00024788
        <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_1_02001_2001_Brief.pdf</filename>
        <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_2_02001_2001_NotaXML.pdf</filename>
        <filename>AB001_AA107_00024788_5_02001_02001_Prov.pdf</filename>
    </ID>
    <ID>ZZ001_AA117_00030393
        <filename>ZZ001_AA117_00030393_1_80001__Brief.pdf</filename>
        <filename>ZZ001_AA117_00030393_2_80001__NotaXML.pdf</filename>
    </ID>
</files>
```

This example has 5 records, but it can be 900 or even higher.

Now I got already the split to ID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/files/folder">
        <xsl:for-each select="file">
                <attachment>
                        <xsl:element name="fileid">
                        <xsl:for-each select="filename/text()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 20)"/>
                                <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                       </xsl:element>
                         <xsl:element name="filename">
                        <xsl:for-each select="filename/text()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                       </xsl:element>
                </attachment>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives me

```
<files count="127" filemask="*.*">
    <attachment>
        <fileid>GH001_GH107_00024788</fileid>
        <filename>GH001_GH107_00024788_1_02001_2001_Brief.pdf</filename>
    </attachment>
    <attachment>
        <fileid>GH001_GH107_00024788</fileid>
        <filename>GH001_GH107_00024788_2_02001_2001_NotaXML.pdf</filename>
    </attachment>
    <attachment>
        <fileid>GH001_GH107_00024788</fileid>
        <filename>GH001_GH107_00024788_5_02001_02001_Prov.pdf</filename>
    </attachment>
    <attachment>
        <fileid>GH001_GH117_00030393</fileid>
        <filename>GH001_GH117_00030393_1_80001.pdf</filename>
    </attachment>
    <attachment>
        <fileid>GH001_GH117_00030393</fileid>
        <filename>GH001_GH117_00030393_2_80001__Notam_XML.pdf</filename>
    </attachment>
```

Hopefully you can advice on grouping, even with Muenchian I can't get it done.
second XMTL I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="groups" match="/files/attachment" use="fileid" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <File>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//attachment[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', fileid)[1])]"/>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attachment">
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="fileid"/></Name>
        <Bestanden>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', filename)">
                    <Name><xsl:value-of select="filename"/></Name>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </Bestanden>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives me.....

```
<File>
<Name>GH001_GH107_00024788</Name>
    <Bestanden/>
<Name>GH001_GH117_00030393</Name>
    <Bestanden/>
<Name>GH001_GH118_00024722</Name>
    <Bestanden/>
<Name>GH001_GH118_00025554</Name>
    <Bestanden/>
'''
```

Comment: It seems like an ordinary grouping problem to group the filename elements by the substring so check your favourite XSLT tutorial or book on grouping or start with https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried with the grouping, but it's killing me on the substring

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Make sure we know which version of XSLT your processor supports. Also clarify the structure of `filename` - esp. if the substring you want to group by has a fixed length.

Comment: Adjusted the issue with steps that I take, I'm a dummy with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet says `version="2.0"`. In XSLT 2.0 it is rather trivial to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/files">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="folder/file/filename" group-by="substring(., 1, 20)">
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </ID>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```